# Add way to go full screen in new Unity WebGL template

Tags: css, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

Generally speaking, when working with Unity WebGL builds, the default template looks like this

[image: Unity default WebGL build]

From the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-templates.html), we can see that when we want to use WebGL templates in Unity we have to create a folder in Assets named **WebGLTemplates**, and a folder named New Template (or whatever name you will) and add an **index.html** there.

[image: Unity WebGL New Template]

Also, the index.html should have a code similar to this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Unity WebGL Player | %UNITY_WEB_NAME%</title>
    <script src="%UNITY_WEBGL_LOADER_URL%"></script>
    <script>
    var unityInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("unityContainer", "%UNITY_WEBGL_BUILD_URL%");
    </script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div id="unityContainer" style="width: %UNITY_WIDTH%px; height: %UNITY_HEIGHT%px; margin: auto"></div>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Then, under Player settings, select that template

[image: Unity WebGL Build new template]

Thing is, this doesn't come with the option to increase to full-size.

[image: Unity New Template without the button to increase size to fullscreen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply add in the index.html template a div with a specific height and width that has the onclick  event `unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1)`, like

```
<div style="height:20px; width: 960px; background: green;" onclick="unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1)"><b>Click here to make it full screen.</b></div>
```

So, change the code to (i decided to put it above the Unity canvas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Unity WebGL Player | %UNITY_WEB_NAME%</title>
    <script src="%UNITY_WEBGL_LOADER_URL%"></script>
    <script>
    var unityInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("unityContainer", "%UNITY_WEBGL_BUILD_URL%");
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div style="height:20px; width: %UNITY_WIDTH%px; background: green;" onclick="unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1)"><b>Click here to make it full screen.</b></div>
    <div id="unityContainer" style="width: %UNITY_WIDTH%px; height: %UNITY_HEIGHT%px; margin: auto"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

And this will output the following

[image: WebGL Unity fullscreen]

and clicking the green area when the game is loaded will make it go fullscreen.

Comment: Is there any way we can avoid clicking green area and make it automatically full screen?

Comment: @Oxygen in this case I really wanted the option. You'll want the `unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1)` set just in a different time than when `onClick`

Comment: I tried calling unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1) on document.ready but it is not working for me. However it works on button click.

Comment: @Oxygen it's best if you ask another question. If you will to reference this one, it might help those trying to help

Comment: Great. Created one. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66905305/how-to-display-unity-webgl-template-in-full-screen-after-loaded)

Answer (score 0):

By default, will come full screen without a footer in WebGL build.

-> Open the index.html file to edit

-> Copy the following code inside the body

```
    <body>
    <div class="webgl-content">
      <div id="unityContainer" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```