# How to display Unity WebGL template in full screen after loaded

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl, unity-webgl

Inspired in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63307534/5675325), we have WebGL setup where we want to load webgl template in full screen mode. It is working fine on button click event as below

```
 <body>
<div class="webgl-content" id="div-parent">
  <div id="unityContainer" ></div>
  <div class="footer">
<button id="buttonClick" style="display:none;" class="fullscreen" onclick="showToggle('unityContainer')"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
function showToggle(elem)
  {
    var div = document.getElementById(elem);
    div.style.display = 'block';
    unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1);
  }
```

Here we have used `unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1);` in `showToggle()` function which is getting called on button click. But if we use the same in `DOMContentLoaded` event its not working.
Ex- We are trying as below -

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1);
});
```

We want to make it full screen without any click event. Can you please guide how can we achieve this?

Comment: You cant. They sid this to avoid browser hijacking. You need the user to instigate it hence you cant just call gofullscreen from unity